# /bin/sh: can't access tty; job control turned off

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, qemu

I have been following the commands from the book "Mastering embedded linux programming" by Chris Simmonds. I have created the toolchain, kernel zImage and busybox file system. When I combine these together to run on QEMU, It should display a root shell prompt.

When I run the command, I get the following.

```
/bin/sh: can't access tty; job control turned off 
input: ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse as /devices/platform/amba/amba:fpga/10007000.kmi/serio1/input/input2
```

When I press enter, I am able to see the root shell prompt and I am able to execute simple shell commands.

However, when I press exit, I get the following error.

```
Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000000

CPU: 0 PID: 1 Comm: sh Not tainted 4.9.13 #1
Hardware name: ARM-Versatile (Device Tree Support)
[<c001b5a4>] (unwind_backtrace) from [<c0018860>] (show_stack+0x10/0x14)
[<c0018860>] (show_stack) from [<c00737f4>] (panic+0xb8/0x230)
[<c00737f4>] (panic) from [<c0024e24>] (do_exit+0x8e8/0x938)
[<c0024e24>] (do_exit) from [<c0025cf8>] (do_group_exit+0x38/0xb4)
[<c0025cf8>] (do_group_exit) from [<c0025d84>] (__wake_up_parent+0x0/0x18)
---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000000
```

How do I resolve this

EDIT:

The following is the QEMU command that I ran

```
QEMU_AUDIO_DRV=none \qemu-system-arm 
-m 256M -nographic 
-M versatilepb 
-kernel ~/linux-4.9.13/arch/arm/boot/zImage 
\-append "console=ttyAMA0,115200 rdinit=/bin/sh" 
-dtb ~/linux-4.9.13/arch/arm/boot/dts/versatile-pb.dtb 
-initrd ~/busybox/initramfs.cpio.gz
```

Comment: Use Buildroot distribution instead. What you did is a hard way to achieve the same and, as you learnt, error prone. In the above you have two issues, somewhere you disabled `tty`, on top of that your busybox contains improper `/etc/inittab`. And so on, so on...

Comment: I'm working on a project which requires it to be done from scratch, and not using any distributions.

Answer (score 4):

(You don't say what your QEMU command line is.)

These error messages generally are what you should expect if you tell the kernel to run /bin/sh directly as its process 1 (eg with "init=/bin/sh" on the kernel command line). First the shell complains that it doesn't have a tty, but it can continue anyway with some facilities disabled. Then, when you eventually tell the shell to exit, because the shell itself is process 1 the kernel complains. (Usually process 1 is supposed to be an "init" program, which runs forever and deals with starting other processes in the system. If "init" ever dies the kernel has nothing else it can do.)

If you were intending to run /bin/sh as your process 1, then this is all normal. If you didn't want to do that, then you have an issue with either your root filesystem or with your command line which means that it isn't properly starting an /sbin/init in the guest, and you should look at why.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to run /bin/sh itself. However, when I remove the -nographic parameter, the root shell doesn't display in qemu. qemu only displays a blank screen. How do I check why /sbin/init isn't starting in the guest. I'm pretty new to this, and quite clueless

Comment: You need to tell the guest kernel where to send its console, and you need to also tell QEMU to send whatever that device is to wherever you want to read it. "console=ttyAMA0" says "send console to serial port. "-nographic" tells QEMU to (among other things) send the serial port to your host terminal window. Depending on what devices you've built into your guest kernel, you can tell it to send the console output somewhere else, and QEMU has a lot of command line options for how you want various device output to be directed. But you need to make the two match, or you'll see no output at all.

Comment: Sorry, which two need to match? If I add "terminal=ttS0" and remove -nographic, I can see the boot commands in the QEMU  window but I can't see the root shell prompt.

Comment: If you have the kernel boot log but not the root shell prompt you probably need to fix your init's config file to start a tty on the right terminal. In sysvinit and busybox init that's /etc/inittab, I think.